# Trying to do a topological sort of a graph in c?

Tags: c, graph, topological-sort

I'm working on code for a topological sort program for graphs. I've implemented the algorithm by doing a depth-first search of the graph, putting each vertex value into a stack, and the popping the values off of the stack and printing them out. This should be producing a topological sort, but so far I consistently get one value less than I put in as far as number of vertices, and none of the number match those I've inputted.

```
status topological_search(graph G, vertex vertex_number, bool visited[], status
 (*p_func_f)()){

  edge *p_edge = NULL;
  int *temp ;
  stack S ;

  init_stack(&S) ;
  temp = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)) ;

  while((p_edge = edge_iterator(G, vertex_number, p_edge)) != NULL){
    if(visited[VERTEX(p_edge)] == FALSE){

      visited[VERTEX(p_edge)] = TRUE ;
      *temp = VERTEX(p_edge) ;
      push(&S, (generic_ptr) temp) ;
      vertex_number = VERTEX(p_edge) ;
    }
  }
  while(!empty_stack(&S)){
    pop(&S, (generic_ptr) &temp) ;
    (*p_func_f)(*temp) ;
  }
  return OK ;
}
```

My stack function all work normally, they've been tested in other programs. Edge_iterator is straight from the textbook and functions normally. Any advice on where my sort is getting the wrong number would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've reedited the code to reflect the changes suggested to vertex_number and the while{..} loop. However now the program will only print he first vertex and nothing else. I can see how before the loop would not visit every node in the graph, however now it only visits one before stopping? Where is this being stopped?

Here's Edge_iterator

```
edge *edge_iterator(graph G, vertex vertex_number, edge *p_last_return){

  vertex other_vertex ;
  if(vertex_number < 0 || vertex_number >= G->number_of_vertices) return NULL ;

  if(p_last_return == NULL) other_vertex = 0 ;
  else other_vertex = VERTEX(p_last_return) + 1 ;

  for( ; other_vertex < G->number_of_vertices; other_vertex++){
    if(G->matrix[vertex_number][other_vertex].weight != UNUSED_WEIGHT)
      return &G->matrix[vertex_number][other_vertex] ;
  }
  return NULL ;
}
```

and the graph implementation.

```
typedef int vertex ;
typedef struct {int weight; vertex vertex_number ;} edge ;

#define UNUSED_WEIGHT (32767)
#define WEIGHT(p_e) ((p_e) -> weight)
#define VERTEX(p_e) ((p_e) -> vertex_number)

typedef enum {directed, undirected} graph_type ;
typedef enum {DEPTH_FIRST, TOPOLOGICAL } searchorder ;

typedef struct {
  graph_type type ;
  int number_of_vertices ;
  edge **matrix ;
}graph_header, *graph ;
```

Comment: How does `edge_iterator` work?  It looks like it's returns the next edge adjacent to vertex number `vertex_number` after `p_edge`.  Where is the recursive call for the depth first traversal?  How much is supposed to be within the `while` loop?  At the moment, it's just the `if { … }`.  It looks like you're setting up a stack, iterating through the edges adjacent to `vertex_number` (but I don't know how `edge_iterator` works, marking the vertices on those edges as visited and putting their values in the stack, and then, popping one value off the stack, calling `p_func_f` with it, and ending.

Comment: You're right, edge_iterator simply returns the next edge adjacent to the vertex after p_edge. The entirety of the While{..} loop is a depth-first traversal, I just couldnt use a funcition call because it is recursive and i needed each edge to be added to the stack as i went through the traversal one edge at a time. And yes, so far the rest of your analysis is correct. however After all this I'm getting one value less than there are edges in the graph printed out for the traversal, and these numbers do not match the ones inputted.

Comment: If you have a graph `G = { (A, B) (B, C) (C, D) }` and you start with the call `topological_search( G, A, [false, false, false], ? )`, that's supposed to start the depth-first traversal at `A`.  When does the depth-first traversal starting at `C` happen?  I don't see that it would ever happen in this code.  When would `C` be marked as visited?

Comment: The depth first-traversal starts at A, and the 'While{...}' loop using 'edge_iterator' to move through each node in the graph so that with each pass through the loop, it is visiting each node and then marking them as visited. For whatever reason this loop continuously stops after one pass, and that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: It's not clear how `edge_iterator` works.  In a graph `G = { (a b), (a c), (b c), (b d), (c d) }`, does `edge_iterator( G, a, p_edge )` iterate through _all_ the edges in the graph, or just those incident to `a`.  I'd expect that since you're passing `a` to `edge_iterator`, it only sets `*p_edge` to `(a b)` and `(a c)`, and not to the other edges.

Comment: We're discussing a lot of code that _isn't_ posted, which will make it very hard to anybody to answer the question.  Can you post the implementation of the graph and of `edge_iterator`?

Comment: Thanks for posting more code.  Look how `edge_iterator` assumes that the `p_edge` passed to it is either `NULL` or the last value that it provided to you.  Since you're updating `vertex_number` in your `while` loop now, the `p_edge` you're passing to `edge_iterator` no longer makes sense.  Suppose you've got a completely connected graph of 5 vertices.  Calling `edge_iterator( G, 0, null )` gives you the edge `(0,1)`.  Calling `edge_iterator( G, 0, (0,0) )` gives you `(0,2)`, (since 1+1 = 2).  But now you're calling `edge_iterator( G, 1, (0,1) )` and getting `(1,2)`, so you never see `(0,1)`.

Comment: In general, a call to `edge_iterator( G, n, (x,y) )` should always have `n == x`, and you're violating that.  (All of that should be in the excellent documentation comments describing the implementation of `edge_iterator`, which I assume you trimmed out for space reasons ;) .)

Comment: How can I fix this to get the correct vertices print out? So far it prints the first two values for the topological sort, however the first one is repeated four times though it is only connected to three other vertices. I'm at a loss as to how to get these values all printed out.

Comment: You mentioned that the `edge_iterator` was taken straight from the textbook, so I did a Google search for it, but only found [these slides](http://www.scribd.com/doc/139858929/91-102-Honors-Computing-II-Final-Project) dated May 10, 2013 (from the future!).  Those slides contain an implementation of `topological_sort` that might be of use to you.  All in all, I suggest you focus on getting a depth-first traversal working, and then modify that for your topological sort.  The wikipedia article on [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) has some pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

Your `vertex_number` is never updated, so you'll never get any further than the starting node. The typical topological sort marks every node with its number of predecessors. Then it goes to all the nodes for which this count is zero and decreases the count for all its successors. This process is repeated until no new nodes with count zero are found. If all nodes at the end have a count of zero, the graph was acyclic and the order in which the nodes were visited is a topological order.